# Probability of $\text{arg}\max_i \mathbb{E}(X_i)$ with limited samples

Tags: confidence-interval, expected-value, multiarmed-bandit

We place ourselves in a multi-armed bandit setting. Each arm yields a stochastic reward in $[0,1]$ under an unknown distribution.

After several pulls ($n_i$ pulls for arm $i$), we collect a dataset of observations:
$$ \mathcal{D} = \{\{x_{ik}\}_{k\in[1,n_i]}\}_{i\in[1,m]}$$

How can I measure the probability that arm $i$ is the one yielding the maximum rewards on average?

----- Old problem explanation -----

I have a set of $m$ independent random variables:
$$\{X_i\}_{i\in[1,m]}$$

We have a dataset where each variable has been iid sampled $n_i$ times: 
$$ \mathcal{D} = \{\{x_{ik}\}_{k\in[1,n_i]}\}_{i\in[1,m]}$$

How can I estimate efficiently (computation-wise and precision-wise) the probability of the argmax of their expectations?
$$ \mathbb{P}\left(\text{arg}\max_i \mathbb{E}(X_i)|\mathcal{D}\right)$$

NB: In my case, $n_i$ values can be very different, like 5 for some variables and $10^4$ for others. $m$ is typically below 10.

Comment: You ask us to estimate something that doesn't exist.  The expectations are a set of $m$ numbers.  At least one of these numbers is largest.  There's no probability associated with the associated index--it is whatever it is according to the laws of arithmetic.  What are you really trying to ask?

Comment: your statement doesnt make any sense. $E(X_i)$ is not a  random variable. what you problably meant is the probability of the maximum over $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{ij}$. In this case you could use the union bound together with the markov inequalitiy to get a bound on this expression (if $n_i$ is fixed).

Comment: Ok, I agree, it's not rigorous. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do better. I mean that my random variables are unknown, and I want the probability, given the observations in $\mathcal{D}$, that their expectation is the highest one.

Comment: It's basically a multi-armed bandit setting, but I do not care about exploring, I just want to know my guess probabilities.

Comment: When you're not sure about a correct mathematical notation, it's *always* better to restate your question in words.  By using notation and language *you* are sure about, and that is consistent with what your readers understands, you can assure correct communication of your question.

Comment: I edited the opening post with a new problem setting (more wordy). I hope it is more understandable.

Comment: Much better, thank you!  May I point out that any answer to this question requires that you first assign a *prior* probability distribution to the arms?  (The answer depends on that prior.)  Without that, (again) the concept of probability does not apply to the statement "arm $i$ is the best."